# Is Visual Studio 2005 Express Edition still legally available anywhere?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, compiler-construction, visual-c++

All the links on the Microsoft site now redirect to the 2008 edition. The problem is the new version won't link with C libraries built with the 2005 edition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this post says something about it

http://apdubey.blogspot.com/2009/04/microsoft-visual-studio-2005-express.html

Comment: The post includes links to .ISO files. Will give it a try!

Comment: well, why else would i post a link to that blog :)

Comment: Nice - I thought for sure MS completely pulled the downloads when 2008 was released.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an MSDN Licence they are all available:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/cc137115.aspx